# float invalid conversion / float unexpected behavior

Tags: c#, floating-point

I'm trying t wrap my mind around the float behavior (in C#). I have take notice of the [floating point precision issue](https://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) thingy.
I want to convert an floating point string to an float, add + 1 to it and convert it back to a string. The input can be with (never more then 5 decimal places) or without decimals, this is different every time. The output has to be again the full notation (no Scientific notation like: 2.017002E+09F)

It seems to work correctly with the decimal conversion.

Any suggestions for the best practice to get it working with a float?

```
var inputDecimalStr = "2017002005"; //2017002005.55 has the same result for the float conversion
float floatRegNr = 0;
float.TryParse(inputDecimalStr, out floatRegNr); // somehow this converts to 2.017002E+09
decimal test1 = decimal.Parse(inputDecimalStr); // this seems to work
float test2 = Convert.ToSingle(test1); // somehow this converts to 2.017002E+09
float test3 = Single.Parse(inputDecimalStr, NumberStyles.Float, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
float test4 = 2017002005F;
float test5 = 2.017002E+09F;
float test6 = 2.017002005E+09F;
double test7 = 234423.33D;

//this works ok
test5.ToString("0." + new string('#', 339));
test1.ToString();
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

Comment: `float` has a precision of 7 significant digits that you can rely on. 2017002005 has 10 significant digits - so yes, you'll be losing information, and adding 1 to that value will have no impact. In terms of scientific notation, that's only relevant when you convert the value back to a string - use the "N" standard format string to avoid the formatting using scientific notation.

Comment: Fundamentally, if you care about the precise decimal value, `decimal` is probably a better option for you. If you don't mind precision issues but need more precision than `float` provides, use `double` instead. Both `double` and `decimal` still have limits to their precision though. It's not a matter of the number of *decimal places* so much as *significant digits*.

Comment: mmm, didn't knew about the 7 places precision of float, thought it was like 30+ places or so. That might be the best thing to do in this case. I need to add up 1 to the input, so no comparison. The decimal seems to work fine for this job. Thanks

Comment: The mantisa ("significant digits") has 23 **bits** (+1 since it is given that the first `1` of the number is omitted). But of course, 23 bits do not give you 23 decimal digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [this tool that shows you the binary representation of float](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), you get that `2017002005` is represented as `0x4ef07204`, which translated back to decimal form becomes `2017001984` (an error of 21 out of the conversion).

If you change the least significative bit of the number (i.e. the minimum change that can be registered) you get `0x4ef07205`, which represents `2017002112` (107 more than `2017002005 + 1`.

If this level of detail is important, you can use fixed point arithmetic. Since you only want to add 1, split the number into integer and decimal parts, add 1 to the integer part and then convert back to String each part separately.

Comment: wauw, didn't thought about that, splitting it and add 1 and then merge it to the string, no floating point logic needed. That's more efficient I think. Thanks